# React Native App crashes on Launch Screen on device

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

I'm starting with React Native, everything works fine in the iOS simulator. I decide to try it on a device.

The app launches, I can play with it, I close/reopen it around 4 or 5 times, and then somewhat randomly the app crashes on Launch Screen (the one with "Powered By React Native"). It just shows the screen, and the app crashes to the iPhone home screen.

Any idea how I can further debug that?

Edit: I added Bugsnag in my AppDelegate.m, but bugsnag doesn't detect anything when the app crashes.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  [BugsnagReactNative start];

  // Rest of code  

}
```

Comment: build the app in debug mode and use [remote js debugging](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu) to see the error thrown while the app crashes.

Comment: The app crashes before the JS is even loaded. I tried to add Bugsnag to see what happens but I receive no crash report when the app crashes.

Comment: @amaurymartiny i have the same issue! did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Zolve I installed Bugsnag and Fabric.io, but didn't find anything. I created a fresh project and now everything works fine.

Comment: just wondering: did you find any solution by now?

Comment: @MrTopf Yes and no, I created a new XCode project, npm installed everything from scratch and everything worked. It seems fragile though.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this issue today. Read a few SO posts and saw one guy mentioned if your app launches and hangs on the splash screen and then crashes with no error it probably has something to one of your npm dependencies.

After digging deeper i saw the react packager was throwing the error

`This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.`

To fix

1. check / clean up dependencies(check for same name declerations)
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*`
4. `npm i`

Comment: Did anyone find out any particular dependencies that were causing this error? I started a project that was (and still is) running fine on the simulator, but when I finally got around to loading it on a device, it boots up fine and I can use it, but if I slide it closed and then try to reopen the app crashes after hanging on the launch screen for 10 seconds or so...

Comment: @mharris7190, i believe this is because the app takes too long to load in the debug mode on iOS. I had the same issue

Comment: @amberv I also believe the same. it takes too long to load in debug mode on iOS and that could be the reason for app close after launch screen. However, on the launch screen, I am unable to open the debug menu to turn off the debug mode. So, is there any other way to do it? Tried by uninstalling but having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

This can caused by many issues it seems. Recently this happened to me and I had to search a bit to find out the exact reason. 
I'll save you guys the trouble by sharing few places I read
 - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14500#issuecomment-348063910
 - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17276#issuecomment-357538208

In my case it was a library issue which I have not linked properly.

-https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/204

So yeah! my point is, it's something we have done or not done. Bit more research would help!!!

Comment: My friend just ruined her whole day to solve this. But no clue.

You Saved her day man!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. My application crashed on emulator device every time I ran the application without throwing any error in the console.

Here are a bunch of solutions that might work:

**Solution 1** Remove `node_modules`

```sh
rm -rf /node_modules
npm install
```

**Solution 2**  Remove `/android/app/build` directory *(This one worked for me)*

```sh
rm -rf /android/app/build
```

After this, uninstall the application from emulator device and then run your application again

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue on real device and it was working fine on simulator. So, i have fixed my issue by given solution

Solution: i have uninstall the application from simulator and then installed it again. This time it showed me the actual error on simulator that i had made mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve this error by running the app in release mode from xcode

1. goto Product->Scheme and then click edit Scheme
2. Select run from left side menu
3. change Debug to Release
4. untick Debug executable
5. now clean the project and run your app in release mode
6. Some time you have to delete pods and install again after doing above
7. look for your error in xcode console in my case VS code has imported a Library I just have to remove that import

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, what triggered it for me though was updating react and react-native.

I did a build after updating and then I experienced the same issue. I downgraded back to the previous versions of react and react-native, but that didn't work for me.

I tried removing node modules, and reinstalling, that didn't help. Then I noticed that when I was building: `react-native run-ios`,

> the files in **ios/build** were not updating

I `rm -rf ios/build/` and then I `react-native run-ios` and the ios/build folder populated. My app ran fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

For me lottie package was creating problem. After removing the package able to launch the package.

Make sure by checking the last package/packages installed

Comment: is it because of the linking or what? , also have you tried linking it manually?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the Firebase `GoogleService-info.plist` file which was missing that is supposed to be present in your project.xcodewrkspc when opened using XCode. Adding that resolved the issue.