# React Native app crash on start - Android

Tags: android, react-native, crash, dependencies

[image]I have a live react native app which was working fine before I integrate firebase cloud messaging. After integration it started crashing app. After that I removed all firebase integration from app and it still kept on crashing everytime I run app on my Android device. It always crash on start on both debug as well as release version of the app.

Here is the logcat:

```
2019-11-27 18:16:25.292 24260-24280/? E/ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new f.ListView.DataSource')
2019-11-27 18:16:25.297 24260-24280/? E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

    --------- beginning of crash
2019-11-27 18:16:25.299 24260-24281/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.telehealthcare, PID: 24260
    com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new f.ListView.DataSource'), stack:
    <unknown>@881:701
    v@2:1474
    <unknown>@6:347
    v@2:1474
    d@2:876
    global code@1026:4

        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:71)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:371)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:150)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Project Level build file:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { // <---- Add this block
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { // <---- Add this block
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

App Level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,
//    bundleAssetName: "app.bundle",
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.telehealcare"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        ndk {
//            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
//        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
//            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
//            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-cardview')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet'))

    // Jitsi Meet
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.+') { transitive = true }


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
//    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
//    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0"
//    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

//     Glide
//    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1") {
//        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "glide"
//    }
//    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1") {
//        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "annotations"
//    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "androidx") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "${targetSdk}.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
//apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "TeleHealCare",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native": "^0.61.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-card-stack-swiper": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-circular-action-menu": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-datepicker-dialog": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta7",
    "react-native-expandable-section-list": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-jitsi-meet": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

MainApplication.java:

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {

            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(),
                    new JitsiMeetPackage(),
                    new RNCardViewPackage(),
                    new ReactNativeContacts()
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }

    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    private static MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "TeleHealCare";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainActivity = this;
    }

    public static void callJitsi(){
        mainActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mainActivity,JitsiActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Please do let me know what is going wrong here. Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native App crashes on Launch Screen on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030067/react-native-app-crashes-on-launch-screen-on-device)

Comment: @Chaurasia, there are lots of questions out there which might have same title but please check logs and other files too. It gives (evaluating 'new f.ListView.DataSource') this error on start of app and crash app on Android. Didn't find any workaround from 3 days searching on Google.

Comment: Could you post the crash logs as well in the question?

Comment: @DarshanPania It is already posted

Comment: @AndiM, show your main application code and activity code

Comment: @Lenoarod, Please check updated code